# GMT Timezone not being detected by SimpleFormat in Android

Tags: java, android

I have a GMT date String coming from server as

```
2015-05-14 12:27:35
```

I am using following code to convert it to text diff.

```
Calendar systemCal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

try {
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    Date date = (Date) formatter.parse(dateString);

    /***********************************/
    CharSequence myDateString = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(date.getTime(), systemCal.getTimeInMillis(), DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS);
    return myDateString.toString().replace("minutes", "min");
```

Now I am getting the problem at

```
    Date date = (Date) formatter.parse(dateString);
```

The result is 
`Thu May 14 05:27:35 GMT+05:00 2015`

Now my question is , why is it using my device default timezone when I have already set GMT timezone and how can I parse it using GMT timezone?

Comment: I would recommend you to use `Joda Time Library`, you will have a lot of more easy way to parse any time into string.

Comment: i don't want to use joda time.

Comment: Have you tried using `formatter.setCalendar(systemCal)` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set GMT for the systemCal. Use the same timezone when you use created Date. It is using default timezome and it makes the difference.

```
    Calendar systemCal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    Date date = (Date) formatter.parse("2015-02-03 10:11:12");
    System.out.println(date); // => Tue Feb 03 05:11:12 EST 2015
    System.out.println(formatter.format(date)); // => 2015-02-03 10:11:12
```